# get UID of recently created user on Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-security, firebasesimplelogin

Is there a way to get the UID of a recently created user?

According to [createUser() documentation](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/createuser.html), it doesn't look like it returns anything.

How would one go about obtaining this information so that we can start storing information about the user?

I know a way that could be achieved would be logging in the user upon creation. But I don't want to overwrite my existing session.

```
var firebaseRef = new Firebase('https://samplechat.firebaseio-demo.com');
  firebaseRef.createUser({
    email    : "bobtony@firebase.com",
    password : "correcthorsebatterystaple"
  }, function(err) {
    if (err) {
      switch (err.code) {
        case 'EMAIL_TAKEN':
          // The new user account cannot be created because the email is already in use.
        case 'INVALID_EMAIL':
          // The specified email is not a valid email.
        case default:
      }
    } else {
      // User account created successfully!
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase recently released an updated JavaScript client (v2.0.5) which directly exposes the user id of the newly-created user via the second argument to the completion callback. Check out the changelog at https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/changelog.html and see below for an example:

```
ref.createUser({
  email: '...',
  password: '...'
}, function(err, user) {
  if (!err) {
    console.log('User created with id', user.uid);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 5):

The above answers are for old firebase.
For the ones looking for new firebase implementation :

```
     firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then(function success(userData){
          var uid = userData.uid; // The UID of recently created user on firebase

          var displayName = userData.displayName;
          var email = userData.email;
          var emailVerified = userData.emailVerified;
          var photoURL = userData.photoURL;
          var isAnonymous = userData.isAnonymous;
          var providerData = userData.providerData;

      }).catch(function failure(error) {

          var errorCode = error.code;
          var errorMessage = error.message;
          console.log(errorCode + " " + errorMessage);

      });
```

Source : [Firebase Authentication Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start#set_an_authentication_state_observer_and_get_user_data)

Comment: this is the true answer

Comment: "undefined" when console.log for the uid

Comment: firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {, #this needs to be added after signup

Comment: @AnoobKBava yupp! but this is only for getting the UID!

Comment: I think userData is much more complex object - to get UID you need to use userData.user.uid.

Answer (score 1):

After the user is created you can authenticate him as mentioned right above the code sample on the page that you link to:

> Creates a new email / password based account using the credentials specified. After the account is created, users may be authenticated with authWithPassword().

then in the `authWithPassword` callback, you can access the new user's `auhtData`. https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/authwithpassword.html

Answer (score 0):

I asked this question on the support forums of firebase and got this answer from Jacob. I hope this helps anyone having the same issue.

Copy and pasted from http://groups.google.com/group/firebase-talk/

---

All you need to do is just authenticate to a different Firebase context. You can do this via an undocumented context argument when creating a new Firebase object.

```
// adminRef will be used to authenticate as you admin user (note the "admin" context - also note that this can be ANY string)
var adminRef = new Firebase("https://<your-firebase>.firebaseio.com", "admin");
adminRef.authWithCustomToken("<token>", function(error, authData) {
  if (error !== null) {  
    // now you are "logged in" as an admin user

    // Let's create our user using our authenticated admin ref
    adminRef.createUser({
      email: <email>,
      password: <password>
    }, function(error) {
      if (error !== null) {
        // let's create a new Firebase ref with a different context ("createUser" context, although this can be ANY string)
        var createUserRef = new Firebase("https://<your-firebase>.firebaseio.com", "createUser");

        // and let's use that ref to authenticate and get the uid (note that our other ref will still be authenticated as an admin)
        createUserRef.authWithPassword({
          email: <email>,
          password: <password>
        }, function(error, authData) {
          if (error !== null) {
            // Here is the uid we are looking for
            var uid = authData.uid;
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Note that we will be releasing a new version of Firebase soon that does return the uid in the createUser() callback. At that point, this somewhat hacky workaround will not be needed.